# invalid operation exception was unhandled (Additional information: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.)

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, datasource, dataadapter

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string conn = "Data Source=JUTT;Initial Catalog=product;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataAdapter adapt;
    SqlConnection con;
    DataTable dt;
    string prnt;
    string sql = null;
    ReportDocument crystal = new ReportDocument();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        crystal.Load(@"c:\users\asad\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\CrystalReport1.rpt");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select id,pd_name,price from sale where id like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(ds, "sale");
        CrystalReport1 rpt = new CrystalReport1();
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        dt = new DataTable();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from sale", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapt.Fill(ds, "sale");
                CrystalReport1 rpt = new CrystalReport1();
                rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
                dt = new DataTable();
    }
}
 }
```

When I click the button2 I'm getting exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll at line rpt.setdatasource

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code you've declared `SqlConnection con;` and never initialized it, but later you're trying to use it in your dataadapters constructors: `adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(".......", con);`

Initialize connection (create instance of it using appropriate connection string) prior to use, for example in form constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    con = new SqlConnection(conn);
}
```

Comment: now this exception is occuring                                    An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Well, this new exption is not directly related to the code you've shown. And its text is pretty self-explanatory: check if referenced assembly is present at specified location